# How to use HardHat tasks directly from the code (and tests)

Tags: testing, hardhat

I'm starting to use HardHat for my project and I created a list of (super useful) tasks ans now I'm trying to implement tests and I want to use some task (like deploy to setup my smart-contract environment without re-writing the code everywhere.

Is this possible ?
Thank

Comment: Pro tip: use my [Solidity template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template) the next time you start a Hardhat project from scratch, to save time on setting up your development environment.

Comment: Yes I already saw your project (multiple times, limit spam, but) I have to admit it's probably the best hardhat boilerplate. I cloned it and check sometime but I prefer understand what I'm doing (as first project, maybe 2de I'll start from your)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can run a Hardhat task programmatically by importing the `run` function from the Hardhat Runtime Environment:

```
import { run } from "hardhat";

run("task-name");
```

See the [docs](https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html#subtasks) for more examples.

Comment: Yes thank. I already read all the hh doc but actually a miss this part ! (Awesome)